# AUTO INCREMENT value for multiple user mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, multi-user

hi guys i am using the code below to get mysql auto increament value its working how ever 
when more than 2 users try to insert row two different table at the same time they are all get the same number and which causes error. 
is there any way to handle this issue 
thanks a lot for your help and ideas 
for example when user1 get the last number 100 on insert.php
at at the same time user2 get the last number 100 to on insert.php
thanks a lot for your help.

```
<input id="id" class="text-input small-input required" name="id" size="20" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php $query = mysql_query( "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'a'" );
$results = mysql_fetch_object( $query );
echo $results->Auto_increment;
?>">  </p>
```

Answer (score 4):

What the heck are you doing on the client side there?

The id of the user should not be visible to the user. The id column of the user table should be set to auto-increment. You can do this in phpMyAdmin or whatever. When the user creates an account, the INSERT that creates the user record will automatically generate a new unique user id using the auto-incrementing "id" field. You can then get the last id created using mysql_insert_id() directly after creating the user record.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ('.$name.', '.$email.')';
mysql_query($query);
$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to determine the auto increment value if you want to insert a row. Instead, don't mention the id column in your insert statement and the database will get the next auto increment value, without causing conflicts.

If you want to know which id has just been inserted, you can use `mysql_insert_id()` after your insert query. That will give you the id value of the row that has just been inserted.